# How to add close button to nebular tabs?

Tags: angular, tabs, nebular

The requirement is to show close button after every tab created

The code snippet is

`<nb-route-tabset [tabs]="tabs"></nb-route-tabset>`

i have checked their documentation and all , but I couldn't find a solution.
Any Solutions?

[image].

Comment: @CodeIgnitor usually tab component won't have close button, your question is not clear! rephrase it with snapshots of expected result and code tried till now!

Comment: i need a close button after every tab title to close the tab

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you can use some like

```
tab1:boolean=true;

  <nb-tab *ngIf="tab1">
    <div *nbTabTitle>
      <span>Transactions</span><nb-icon icon="close-outline"></nb-icon>
    </div>
    <p>List of <strong>transactions</strong>.</p>
  </nb-tab>
```